# Извлечение записей соответствующих определенным месяцам

Tags: mysql, sql

представим что есть такая база

```
create table monthes(month_id int,
                            date datetime);
insert into monthes values(1,'2016-08-01 00:00:00')
,(2,'2016-09-01 00:00:00')
,(3,'2016-06-01 00:00:00')
,(4,'2016-07-01 00:00:00')
;
```

и есть массив (на php)

```
$array = ['september', 'august'];
```

Как по данному массиву можно выбрать первую и вторую запись?

вот мои "потуги".

```
select * from monthes 
where 
DATENAME(month, `monthes.date` ) = 'september'
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/82496f/2)

Comment: хочу как то через IN пройтись, но не знаю как

Comment: А какая СУБД используется? Какие функции можно использовать? Или нужно кросс-решение, которое будет работать во всех СУБД?

Comment: mysql, вы уже ответили спасибо))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В различных СУБД различные механизмы и функции для работы с календарными данными. Более или менее компактное решение зависит от конкретного диалекта. Например, в случае СУБД MySQL можно воспользоваться функцией `DATE_FORMAT()`, которая позволяет извлечь название полное название месяца. Для извлечения записей для группы месяцев можно воспользоваться следующим запросом

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `monthes`
WHERE
  DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%M') IN ('september', 'august')
```

Для одиночного месяца запрос может выглядеть так

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  `monthes`
WHERE
  DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%M') = 'september'
```